# Program 'python.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am using VSCode for the first time and I have a problem to import anything. When I originally installed (yesterday), I could import built in module like the **os**. But I am using for data science purposes so I have Anaconda. I have changed python path on VSCode to the Ananconda one and now it shows Ananconda3: conda at the bottom.
But every time I am trying to import anything I have the following message:

**Program 'python.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1**

Comment: Is that the entire error output? How did you configure Conda with VSC? Have you seen https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments ?

Comment: @AMC, Thanks for your answer. My problem was the conda  configuration. For some reason the setup of the computer did not allow anaconda in the right place, posing enormous problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not access the python from the conda location. However, the normal python worked well. That could have been a problem with the work computer configuration or internet security or maybe something else. I changed the conda location to ProgramData and it worked fine.